# Can you spot any problems with this DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, reference

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EyesLib
{
    class Class1
    {

    public void drawEyes(int lookAtX, int lookAtY, int width, int height, Graphics eyeArea)
    {
        int xleft = 0, yleft = 0, xright = 0, yright = 0, xpleft = 0, ypleft = 0, xpright = 0, ypright = 0, reye = 0, rpupil = 0;
        xleft = width / 3;
        yleft = height / 2;
        xright = 2 * width / 3;
        yright = height / 2;
        reye = width / 9;
        rpupil = reye / 2;
        Bitmap bufl = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bufl);

        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, xleft - reye, yleft - reye, 2 * reye, 2 * reye);
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, xright - reye, yright - reye, 2 * reye, 2 * reye);
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, xleft - reye, yleft - reye, 2 * reye, 2 * reye);
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, xright - reye, yright - reye, 2 * reye, 2 * reye);
        if ((lookAtX != xleft) || (lookAtY != yleft))
        {
            xpleft = (int)Math.Round(xleft + (reye - rpupil) / (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(lookAtX - xleft, 2) + Math.Pow(lookAtY - yleft, 2))) * (lookAtX - xleft));
            ypleft = (int)Math.Round(yleft + (reye - rpupil) / (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(lookAtX - xleft, 2) + Math.Pow(lookAtY - yleft, 2))) * (lookAtY - yleft));
        }
        else
        {
            xpleft = xleft;
            ypleft = yleft;
        }
        if ((lookAtX != xright) || (lookAtY != yright))
        {
            xpright = (int)Math.Round(xright + (reye - rpupil) / (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(lookAtX - xright, 2) + Math.Pow(lookAtY - yright, 2))) * (lookAtX - xright));
            ypright = (int)Math.Round(yright + (reye - rpupil) / (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(lookAtX - xright, 2) + Math.Pow(lookAtY - yright, 2))) * (lookAtY - yright));
        }
        else
        {
            xpright = xright;
            ypright = yright;
        }
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, xpleft - rpupil, ypleft - rpupil, 2 * rpupil, 2 * rpupil);
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, xpright - rpupil, ypright - rpupil, 2 * rpupil, 2 * rpupil);
        eyeArea.DrawImage(bufl, 0, 0);
        g.Dispose();



    }

    public void closeEyes(int width, int height, Graphics eyeArea)
    {
        int xleft = 0, yleft = 0, xright = 0, yright = 0, reye = 0, rpupil = 0;
        xleft = width / 3;
        yleft = height / 2;
        xright = 2 * width / 3;
        yright = height / 2;
        reye = width / 9;
        rpupil = reye / 2;
        eyeArea.FillEllipse(Brushes.Gray, xleft - reye, yleft - reye, 2 * reye, 2 * reye);
        eyeArea.FillEllipse(Brushes.Gray, xright - reye, yright - reye, 2 * reye, 2 * reye);

    }
}
}
```

Despite building correctly,it's not being recognized by Visual Studio when referenced.
It's also not a .NET version problem. I tried all 4/4.5/Client Profile etc. I even redid the project, that I'm linking the DLL to and still the problem remains.

Comment: Please make the title relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep.  Your class isn't public.  Try making Class1 public and I have a feeling it'll solve your problem.

As for why, if you do not explicitly provide an access modifier, a class will default to internal.  Since you are referencing your class in an external assembly, Intellisense can't help you find it, since it is not actually accessible to your external invoker.

Comment: @user4421334 My pleasure.  I updated my answer to give you more context.  If it solved your problem, a selection as the correct answer would be greatly appreciated :)